# Force annotated field to contain annotated class in java

Tags: java, spring, annotations

This is just opposite to [Force annotated Class to contain annotated Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132396/force-annotated-class-to-contain-annotated-field?rq=1).

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContainsNonEditableFields {}

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NonEditable {}
```

If any of the class field is annotated with @NonEditable; then how to force that class should be annotated with @ContainsNonEditableFields ?

Comment: At compile time or at runtime?  What have you tried?

Comment: @JimGarrison compile time only. And currently i dont have any idea how to make this cross relationship between the annotations :(

Comment: @JimGarrison Jim could you please help me here ..?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with AspectJ.

But the Key Idea is to use AspectJs [declare warning or errors](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-decp.html) function, to declare a error for each field with `@NonEditable` annotation in a class that does not have a `@ContainsNonEditableFields` annotation.

*(unfortunately I can not provide a working example out of the box, but I thing somebody at stackoverflow can help you if you ask the right question)*

```
declare error : @annotation(NonEditable) &&
                   ! @annotation(ContainsNonEditableFields)      
                : "the class need ContainsNonEditableFields annotation";
```

This code is only some kind of scribble, it is not working aspectj syntax!